# How to capture final response in case of HTTP redirect

Tags: npm, npm-request

I'm using the npm-request package to capture HTTP response. In case of status code `304`, it captures an empty body.

```
r(reqOptions, (err, response, body) => {
    logger.info("Response: " + response.statusCode);
    logger.debug(body)
}).pipe(res)
```

How can I capture data in case of 304 status code?

Answer (score 0):

`request` library is no more actively supported. Hence, I have moved to `axios` which solved my problem. In axios, I'm able to push the response data stream to file system and to HTTP response further.